# Jquery get image path different results IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, firefox, path

I have this code:

```
var fullpath = $(this)[0].src;
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = fullpath;
var imgpath = a.pathname + a.search;
```

Firefox (and most other browsers) output /showroom/roth_tar/pictures/tar8/11.jpg

bur IE outputs showroom/roth_tar/pictures/tar8/11.jpg (without first slash) and it fails in php then.

How can I fix it? Thx!

Comment: What does the markup look like?

Comment: *How can I fix it?*: Prepend a slash if it does not exist?

Comment: in markup src='/pictures/tar1/11.jpg'

Comment: What does `$(this).attr("src")` return?

Comment: @Sobakinet: *"in markup src='/pictures/tar1/11.jpg'"* With respect, then, I don't see how IE could be returning something without the leading slash. The `src` reflected property of an `img` will be the fully-resolved path to the image (which may not be the same as its `src` attribute). The `src` **attribute**, on most browsers, will be what you actually put in the `src="..."` attribute in the tag. [See this, for instance.](http://jsbin.com/apumir) But in neither case will IE drop the leading slash inappropriately; it is, as you say, significant. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @Sobakinet: Based on your answer above, your markup clearly doesn't include the leading slash, and that's the problem. If you can prove that wrong, please do so with full code in the question and a link to a live example on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net demonstrating the problem.

Comment: ok, i've done it lile +Felix Kling adviced. Thx

Comment: +T.J.Crowder it did not metter if there were '/' or not in src. I've doublechecked it... maybe i've got some strange IE version...

Comment: @Sobakinet: No, there's something else going on; I would strongly recommend finding out what that is rather than just fixing it (though fixing it is, of course, the quickest way forward for now). I tested IE6 and IE9; it's going to be reliable in 7 and 8 if those two do the same thing (and again, it would be a massive bug). Again, feel free to post an example, but I'm quite sure you'll find that in making that sample, you uncover the magic ingredient causing the behavior (or you'll post it and we'll help you figure it out). Best,

Comment: I probably should have added that of course you should only do this if you ruled out any error from your side. You *should not* get different values in IE and Firefox.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use @felixkling's suggestion - http://jsfiddle.net/cgYSF

Comment: yep, i've made it so, but via php